# Garbage Collector won't free memory of some objects

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have these methods:

```
public void GetImage(JObject o)
{
    var imageFile = o["file"].ToString();

    if (!File.Exists(imageFile))
    {
         SendMessage("File does not exist");
         return;
    }

    using (var image = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
    {
         var serialized = GetImageAsString(image);

         var ob = new JObject
              {
                  { COMMAND, (int) Command.GetImage },
                  { "content", serialized }
              };

          Send(ob);
          ob = null;
          serialized = null;
    }
}

private static string GetImageAsString(Image image)
{
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
     {
          image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
     }
}

private static void Send(JObject o)
{
     var package = EncodeContent(o);
     _stream.Write(package, 0, package.Length);
     _stream.Flush();

     Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
}

private static byte[] EncodeContent(JObject o)
{
     return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(GetMessageSize(o), o, (char) 3));
}
```

After the execution of `GetImage` with a 612KB `JPEG` file, the memory consumption of my application goes 10MB up, and even after several minutes those 10MB are not disposed.

- How can I be certain that the objects generated by `GetImage` will be
  eligible by `GC`?
- How can I make sure the objects generated by
  `GetImage` will not be allocated for long after the method execution?

Comment: If you issue another GetImage, does it rise by another 10MB? And if so, how many times can you do that before it drops down again?

Comment: Do you ever dispose or reset `_stream`?

Comment: Implementing IDisposable will ensure your objects are accessible by the GC, but .NET has a certain amount of overhead, so I wouldn't really worry about it.  If you want granular control over memory usage, .NET isn't the best way to go

Comment: If I call `GetImage` again it rises another 10MB, altough I have not tried more than a couple times.
I never dispose `_stream`, cannot dispose the underlying stream.

Comment: GC is free not to release the memory unless a memory pressure forces it to do so. (10MB is not big).

Comment: I suggest using a profiler and see if indeed there is a leak and if so, where it originates (who keeps references to instances that otherwise should be collected).

Comment: There is any way at all for me to disposed these 10MB as soon as I can?

What profiler do you suggest?

Comment: That depends on what kind of objects keep hanging. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC determines itself when it will free up the memory - basically when it feels pressure to free up memory, it will do so.  If it has no such pressure, it wont.

Since your JPEG is a large object, the GC will not put it in the Gen1 collector, which gets cleaned up much more than the other, longer lived generations.  Therefore it's even less likely it will have pressure to collect.

To check if it is just not collecting it because it doesn't feel like it, or if it's a leak, try doing the following set of calls, and see what happens with your memory.  If it doesn't drop, then you may have a leak (though my guess is it's just the GC not collecting).  (Disclaimer - I do NOT recommend you leave this code in your production code.  Let the GC do its thing).

```
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
```